# How do I use (n)curses in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unix, curses

I'd like to create a progress bar to indicate the status of an a batch job in `Ruby`.

I've read some [tutorials](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) / [libraries](http://ncurses-ruby.berlios.de/) on using *(n)curses*, none of which were particularly helpful in explaining how to create an *"animated"* progress bar in the terminal or using curses with `Ruby`.

I'm already aware of using a separate thread to monitor the progress of a given job, I'm just not sure how to proceed with drawing a progress bar.

---

**Update**

[ProgressBar](http://0xcc.net/ruby-progressbar/) class was incredibly straight-forward, perfectly solved my problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might be able to get some implementation ideas from the [Ruby/ProgressBar library](http://0xcc.net/ruby-progressbar/), which generates text progress bars. I stumbled across it a couple of months back but haven't made any use of it.

Comment: Take note: Current as of 2012, implementations of ***ncurses*** in the ruby language use the [ffi-ncurses](https://github.com/seanohalpin/ffi-ncurses) gem. ***Curses*** is included in the STDLIB of ruby.

Comment: Update Note: As of Ruby 2.1.0 (some time in 2014) - curses in the STDLIB has been removed and [is now a gem](https://github.com/ruby/curses)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think curses is overkill in this case.  While the curses lib is nice (and I frequently use it myself) it's a PITA to relearn every time I haven't needed it for 12 months which has to be the sign of a bad interface design.

If for some reason you can't get on with [the progress bar lib Joey suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306/#1318) roll your own and release it under a pretty free licence for instant kudos :)

Comment: @MeNoMore "PITA" is not code. It is an acronym for "pain in the arse". Do not use code formatting for such things.

Comment: @Andrew Barber :) you got me laughing now i rreally didnt know that with PITA as "pain in the arse", just learned something, where i come from PITA is something totally different (Hint: even there it isnt code :), you can google it), thank you anyway

Answer (score 4):

Very late answer and sorry for self promotion, but I created [library](https://rubygems.org/gems/progress) to show progress in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, curses works out of the box, ncurses doesn't, and for a progress bar curses should be sufficient. So, use curses instead of ncurses.

Also, both curses and ncurses are wafer-thin wrappers around the c library - that means you don't really need Ruby-specific tutorials.

However, on the [site for the PickAxe](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/source_code) you can download all the code examples for the book. The file "ex1423.rb" contains a curses demo which plays Pong - that should give you plenty of material to get you going.