# Learning Ruby Curses

Tags: ruby, curses

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for learning Ruby with Curses? I just can't seem to find one and the doc is very vague. I have never used curses before so I really don't know much about it.

Answer (score 17):

You can see the basics in action at the [curses tic tac toe](https://github.com/grosser/tic_tac_toe)

Answer (score 3):

Here's some suggestions from a previous question:
[How do I use ncurses in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306/how-do-i-use-ncurses-in-ruby)

Comment: ncurses is not curses.