# Print and update multiple lines in fixed position

Tags: ruby, printing, terminal, console

I would like to print an output like the following in a fixed position while the numbers in the block keep updating every couple of seconds. It is similar to what `top` does.

```
Jobs monitor:
+-----------------------------------------+
| Waiting | Launched | Running | Finished |
+-----------------------------------------+
|   319   |   364    |   94    |   201    |
+-----------------------------------------+
Elapsed time: 21s
```

Is there a way to do that?

With only one line, I could do it with `STDOUT.flush` and `"\r"`, but it does not work for multiple lines since the carriage will put the cursor at the beginning of the new line only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [curses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html) library is one way to make this work. It allows you to write to locations on a 2-d screen so you're not constrained to the current line. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309218/learning-ruby-curses) has some good resources for learning curses.

Comment: Is it a way of doing it without installing any gem? Playing with the output or something like that? Curses does not seem to be available without installing it.

Comment: you could probably re-implement curses with things like [ANSI control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that seems pretty painful though. Nothing else comes to mind immediately.