# Ways to control text-mode console output with ruby

Tags: ruby, console

I'm interested in writing a text-mode "gui" application with ruby. This means I need to have a way to output text anywhere I want in the terminal, move cursor around and react directly to different keypresses. Using color would also be a nice plus.

Is [`ncurses`](http://ncurses-ruby.berlios.de/) the only (or clearly best) way to go, or are there other options to consider? I'm not saying there's anything wrong with `ncurses`, but I like to be aware of my options. (For information about using `ncurses` with Ruby, there's already [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306/how-do-i-use-ncurses-in-ruby).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C there were two historic choices for terminal blob graphics and text addressing: use ncurses or use the lower-level termcap/terminfo library. I imagine that for Ruby only ncurses bindings exist.

So I'm guessing that there are these choices:

- Use ncurses as you mentioned
- Use the lower-level termcap/terminfo lib. This doesn't really make any sense, plus you would probably have to make the ruby bindings yourself.
- There are a number of widget libraries that wrap ncurses. See [Newt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_(programming_library)), and [Dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_(software)), and [CDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_Development_Kit).  You would probably have to create the Ruby bindings.

Comment: Well, since nobody came forward with any other options, I take it to mean this has it covered. Accepted, and thanks!

Comment: [ruby-terminfo](https://github.com/genki/ruby-terminfo) has been around since 2007.  Depending on the platform, it uses ncurses (see [source](https://github.com/genki/ruby-terminfo/blob/master/extconf.rb)).